# Show all files contain same partial class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, partial-classes, resharper-6.1

I have a partial class 
`public partial class myClass`

defines in different files,
e.g. myClass1.cs, myClass2.cs, etc.

Is there a way for resharper or Visual studio built-in functionalities to find all the files belong to the same partial class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Use [*Navigate to Related Files*](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Related_Files.html).

If you use the IntelliJ/ReSharper2 keyboard bindings, it's <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you left the default settings as the Visual Studio settings for shortcut keys when installing ReSharper, the default could also be Ctrl + Alt + F7 (at least in ReSharper 8)